# how to import XPDL 2.2 into Bonita BPM

Tags: bpmn

i made few BPM diagram using bizagi and now i want to change to bonita BPM because of his license.

so i export the diagrams in XPDL and then i try to import it in bonita but dont work because bizagi only export in XPDL 2.2 and bonita support XPDL 1.1 or BPMN 2 but not XPDL 2.2

i tried to use a convert that i found on internet but dont work (http://www.businessprocessincubator.com/convert-an-xpdl-to-bpmn.html)

how can import those diagram in bonita?

Comment: I checked and there is no easy way to do it. What kind of process do you want to convert?